# Adding row with null field to another row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my SQL Server database that looks like:

Date  Hours  Name 
11-01      3               a
11-01      4              b
11-01      6               null
12-01      2               a
12-01      3               c
12-01      1              null

I want to add the hours from the "null" column into the "a" column for each month.  So it would look like:
Date  Hours  Name 
11-01      9                a
11-01      4                b
12-01      3                a
12-01      3                c

The only way I was able to get this to work was by modifying the table prior to the select to prevent the null from showing up.  But I'd like to be able to do this without modifying the database.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for clear, concise question. A lot of new users write verbose paragraphs of irrelevant info. Keep it up :)

Comment: Please clarify: your desired results show 9 for 'a', when it should seemingly produce 10 per the logic you seem to be asking for.  Is this a miscalculation, or am I misunderstanding what you're asking for?

Answer (score 3):

This'll do it for you - grouping by name or 'a' (when name is null) conditionally, and taking the sum of hours from there.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Hours) AS Hours, MAX(Name) AS Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 'a' ELSE Name END)
```